# Parse.com setting ACL on cloud function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, acl

I am able to set `setPublicReadAccess` using the code below however I would like to lock the `ACL` to the user only.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Programme", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var publicReadACL = new Parse.ACL();
  publicReadACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

  request.object.setACL(publicReadACL);
  response.success();
});
```

I have also tried

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Programme", function(request) {
  var user = Parse.User.current();
  if(typeof request.object.getACL() === "undefined") {
    var newACL = new Parse.ACL();
    newACL.setReadAccess(user.id,true);
    newACL.setWriteAccess(user.id,true);

    request.object.setACL(newACL);
    request.object.save();
  }
});
```

Which does not work either.

Comment: Did you try just `new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current())` ? And does it get into your `if` statement (log it)?

Comment: Ok I have got this working by sending the user.id I the request object as a string. However I believe that each request carried a request.user which was the user id?

Comment: It does. I actually have exactly the same code as you running in one project I think and it's working fine

Comment: I added `console.log('user is:' + request.user);` and I get
`I2015-04-09T16:00:30.984Z] user is:null`

Answer (score 3):

The ACL of your ParseObject might have been already initialized, so you should use`request.object.existed() == false` instead of `typeof request.object.getACL() === "undefined"`.

Also if you don't want your object to be public you have to `newACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);` and `newACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false);`

It works for me

```
    Parse.Cloud.afterSave("YourObject", function(request) {
      var user = Parse.User.current();

      // check if the object was just created
      if(request.object.existed() == false){
        var newACL = new Parse.ACL();
        newACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
        newACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
        newACL.setReadAccess(user.id,true);
        newACL.setWriteAccess(user.id,true);

        request.object.setACL(newACL);
        request.object.save();
      }
    });
```

Comment: according to https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.ACL.html you shouldn't need to set public access to false (as a new ACL has "no permissions for anyone") - though being thorough is better than being stung when it's changed